# Multiprocessing: Shared memory slower than pickling?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to get myself acquainted to multiprocessing in Python. Performance does not work out as I expected; therefore, I am seeking advice how to make things work more efficiently.

Let my first state my objective: I basically have a bunch `data` of lists. Each of these lists can be processed independently, say by some dummy routine `do_work`. My implementation in my actual program is slow (slower than doing the same in a single process serially). I was wondering if this is due to the pickling/unpickling overhead involved into multiprocess programming.

Therefore, I tried to implement a version using shared memory. Since the way how I distribute the work makes sure that no two processes try to write to the same piece of memory at the same time, I use `multiprocessing.RawArray` and `RawValue`. As it turns out, the version with shared memory is *even slower*.

My code is as follows: `main_pass` and `worker_pass` implement the parallelisation using return-statements, while `main_shared` and `worker_shared` use shared memory.

```
import multiprocessing, time, timeit, numpy as np
data = None

def setup():
    return np.random.randint(0,100, (1000,100000)).tolist(), list(range(1000))

def do_work(input):
    output = []
    for j in input:
        if j % 3 == 0:
            output.append(j)
    return output

def main_pass():
    global data
    data, instances = setup()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        start = time.time()
        new_blocks = pool.map(worker_pass, instances)
        print("done", time.time() - start)

def worker_pass(i):
    global data
    return do_work(data[i])

def main_shared():
    global data
    data, instances = setup()
    data = [(a := multiprocessing.RawArray('i', block), multiprocessing.RawValue('i', len(a))) for block in data]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        start = time.time()
        pool.map(worker_shared, instances)
        print("done", time.time() - start)
        new_blocks = [list(a[:l.value]) for a, l in data]
        print(new_blocks)
        
def worker_shared(i):
    global data
    array, length = data[i]
    new_block = do_work(array[:length.value])
    array[:len(new_block)] = new_block
    length.value = len(new_block)

import timeit
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: main_pass(), number=1))
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: main_shared(), number=1))
```

the timing I get:

```
done 7.257717132568359
10.633161254
done 7.889772891998291
38.037218965
```

So the version run first (using return) is way faster than the one writing the result to shared memory.

Why is this?

Btw., is it possible to measure the time spent on pickling/unpickling conveniently?

Info: I am using python 3.9 on MacOS 10.15.

Comment: Your benchmark seems to be based on faulty assumptions and conclusions. First, by having `data` as global the way you are doing it, there is no pickling/unpickling involved in either multiprocessing case. Second, I would ignore the `timeit` values, which includes all the setup and done before calling `map` and all the processing done following the call to `map`, which is totally different for both cases. Third, `worker_shared` is doing more processing than `worker_pass`, so I would expect the shared memory version to be a bit slower. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @Booboo but isn't the returned output from `worker_pass` passed by pickling? In what sense does `worker_shared` do more work? It computes some output and writes it to shared memory, while `worker_pass` computes some output and returns it.

Answer (score -1):

What you say about the *returned output* from `worker_pass` being done by pickling is true but that additional overhead is clearly does not seem to compensate for the additional work being done by `worker_shared` to "repack" the `RawArray` instances. Where a performance improvement is achieved is when you *are* forced to use pickling for the `worker_pass` case as when you are on platforms that use `spawn` to create new processes.

In the following `spawn` demo I seed the random number generator with a specific value so I get the same generated values for both runs and I print out the sum of all the returned random numbers just to ensure that both runs are doing equivalent processing. It is clear that using shared memory arrays performs better now if you are only timing the pool-creation (where the overhead is for the non-shared memory case) and `map` times. But when you include the additional setup time and post-processing time required for the use of the shared memory arrays, the difference in times is not that significant:

```py
import multiprocessing, time, timeit, numpy as np

def setup():
    np.random.seed(seed=1)
    return np.random.randint(0,100, (1000,100000)).tolist(), list(range(1000))

def init_process_pool(the_data):
    global data
    data = the_data

def do_work(input):
    output = []
    for j in input:
        if j % 3 == 0:
            output.append(j)
    return output

def main_pass():
    data, instances = setup()
    start = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_process_pool, initargs=(data,)) as pool:
        new_blocks = pool.map(worker_pass, instances)
        print("done", time.time() - start)
        print(sum(sum(new_block) for new_block in new_blocks))

def worker_pass(i):
    global data
    return do_work(data[i])

def main_shared():
    data, instances = setup()
    data = [(a := multiprocessing.RawArray('i', block), multiprocessing.RawValue('i', len(a))) for block in data]
    start = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_process_pool, initargs=(data,)) as pool:
        pool.map(worker_shared, instances)
        print("done", time.time() - start)
        new_blocks = [list(a[:l.value]) for a, l in data]
        #print(new_blocks)
        print(sum(sum(new_block) for new_block in new_blocks))

def worker_shared(i):
    global data
    array, length = data[i]
    new_block = do_work(array[:length.value])
    array[:len(new_block)] = new_block
    length.value = len(new_block)

import timeit
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: main_pass(), number=1))
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: main_shared(), number=1))
```

Prints:

```
done 17.68915629386902
1682969169
20.2827687
done 3.9250364303588867
1682969169
23.2993996
```